# Connection with SQLite from web app: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, driver, java-ee-6

I downloaded the latest version of the sqlite for java driver (sqlite-jdbc-3.16.1.jar) at https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/
When I use it for my java-web application I have this error: "`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc: sqlite: tennis.db`"

The same driver works with a desktop application.

Here is my class Connection:

```
public class ConnexionDB {

    private Connection conx = null;
    private final String urlBDD = "jdbc:sqlite:tennis.db";

    private String MessageError = "Pas d'erreurs ! ";

    public ConnexionDB() {
        this.openConnexion();
        this.createDataBase();
    }

    private String getMessageError() {
        return MessageError;
    }

    private void setMessageError(String MessageError) {
        this.MessageError = MessageError;
    }

    private void openConnexion(){
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            this.conx = DriverManager.getConnection(urlBDD);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            this.setMessageErreur("BD_Connexion:ouvrirConnexion:Erreur::: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void closeConnexion() {
        try {
            this.conx.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            this.setMessageError("BD_Connexion:closeConnexion:Erreur::: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Object[][] selectExe(String requete) {
        Object[][] data = new Object[1][1];

        try {
            if (requete.toLowerCase().contains("select")) {
                Statement ReqExe = this.conx.createStatement();
                ResultSet ReqRes = ReqExe.executeQuery(requete);

                int nbreColonne = ReqRes.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
                int nbreLigne = this.nombreLigne(requete);

                data = new Object[nbreLigne + 1][nbreColonne];

                for (int i = 1; i <= nbreColonne; i++) {
                    data[0][i - 1] = ReqRes.getMetaData().getCatalogName(i);
                }

                int cmptr = 1;
                while (ReqRes.next()) {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= nbreColonne; i++) {
                        data[cmptr][i - 1] = ReqRes.getString(i);
                    }
                    cmptr++;
                }
                ReqRes.close();
                ReqExe.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            this.setMessageError("BD_Connexion:selectExe:Error::: " + ex.getMessage());
        }

        return data;
    }

    private int nombreLigne(String requete) {
        int nbreLigne = 0;

        try {
            if (requete.toLowerCase().contains("select")) {

                Statement ReqExe = this.conx.createStatement();
                ResultSet ReqRes = ReqExe.executeQuery(requete);
                //
                while (ReqRes.next()) {
                    nbreLigne++;
                }
                ReqRes.close();
                ReqExe.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            this.setMessageErreur("BD_Connexion:nombreLigne:Erreur::: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return nbreLigne;
    }

    public boolean updateExe(String requete) {
        boolean data = false;

        try {
            if (!requete.toLowerCase().contains("select")) {

                Statement ReqExe = this.conx.createStatement();

                int reqInfo = ReqExe.executeUpdate(requete);

                if (reqInfo > 0) {
                    data = true;
                }
                ReqExe.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            this.setMessageErreur("BD_Connexion:updateExe:Erreur::: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return data;
    }

    private void createDataBase() {
        try {
            Statement ReqExe = this.conx.createStatement();

            String tableAdherent = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ADHERENT\n"
                    + "(NUMEROADHERENT INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n"
                    + "NOM VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "PRENOM VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "ADDRESSE VARCHAR(50),\n"
                    + "TELEPHONE VARCHAR(24),\n"
                    + "EMAIL VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,\n"
                    + "PASSWORD VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL);";
            ReqExe.execute(tableAdherent);


            String tableTouroi = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TOURNOI\n"
                    + "(CODETOURNOI INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n"
                    + "NOM VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "DATE VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "LIEU VARCHAR(30));";
            ReqExe.execute(tableTouroi);


            String tableInscription = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS INSCRIPTION\n"
                    + "(IDINSCRIPTION INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,\n"
                    + "NUMEROADHERENT INTEGER NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "CODETOURNOI INTEGER NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "DATEINSCRIPTION VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,\n"
                    + "CONSTRAINT fk_numeroAdherent Foreign KEY (NUMEROADHERENT) references ADHERENT(NUMEROADHERENT),\n"
                    + "CONSTRAINT fk_codeTournoi Foreign KEY (CODETOURNOI) references TOURNOI(CODETOURNOI));";
            ReqExe.execute(tableInscription);

            ReqExe.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Echecs : Creation des tables");
            Logger.getLogger(ConnexionDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

What to do ?

Comment: i think there are a space between `: s` here `jdbc: sqlite: tennis.db`

Comment: I put spaces but it still does not work !

Comment: no i meant that the error contain spaces `...found for jdbc: sqlite: tennis.db"` so you have to check your url

Comment: The error and code do not match, the code shown cannot have triggered the exception as quoted, because the URL in the code doesn't contain spaces, while the one in the error does contain spaces.

Comment: Yes, but i don't understand why ? I need a help please !